# Anonymous cast type exception

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, xaml

I have a LINQ to EF query in which I select some columns of the entity t_Klantenhistory. This query is the items source of the datagrid dgHistory. Auto generate columns is set to true. When I want to get the selected item from dgHistory, the code throws an error stating:

> "Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType5`5[System.Int32,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String]' to type 'AOV.t_Klantenhistory'."

This works really fine when I select all the columns, but I don't want all the columns. How can I solve this problem?

CODE:

```
public KlantenHistory()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    entities = new AOVEntities();

    var query = (from cust in entities.t_Klantenhistory
                 select new
                 {
                     cust.ID,
                     cust.IdNo,
                     cust.Naam,
                     cust.Voornamen,
                     cust.VolgNo
                 });

    dgHistory.DataContext = entities.t_Klantenhistory;
    dgHistory.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    dgHistory.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
}

private void btToonHistory_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    s_history = new SpecifiekeHistory();
    t_Klantenhistory klant = (t_Klantenhistory)dgHistory.SelectedItem;
    s_history.GetKlantHistory(klant.ID);
    s_history.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an anonymous type for stocking the result of your query. So this is not a `t_Klantenhistory` instance that you retrieve.

You can solve the problem by using the dynamic keyword:

```
dynamic klant = dgHistory.SelectedItem;
s_history.GetKlantHistory(klant.ID);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked like a charm. I also asked another question but no one ever answered it. Would you please like to help me by answering that question?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to cast anonymous type object to `t_Klantenhistory` in your `btnToonHistory_Click` event. In your select statement you are using `new` keyword and that is creating an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx) object.

You can create a new temporary class and project to that. You can't project to `t_Klantenhistory`, because its a generated class from the framework.

The otherway could be to select everything from the table with `select cust`, instead of `select new ...`, and then hide the columns you don't want to show in your Grid `dgHistory`.

Comment: @aateeque, OP is using `LINQ to EF`, and querying like `entities.t_Klantenhistory`, so yes it appears it is generated through framework.

Comment: get you now! You mean its EF entity name

Comment: @aateeque, t_Klantenhistory is a generated class from the framework.